# I want to use Microsoft Teams HTTP request that sends a message in chat. How do I get my TeamsID and ChannelID

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

As the title says I want to create messages in our teams channel via HTTP Calls. This is the documentation I am referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

It says that I have to do a request like this : POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages

But I have no clue how to get those ID's. Can somebody please guide me?

Best regards,

Stan

I've tried to copy the invitation link and somehow deduce from the link which part is which ID, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can find these IDs by following these steps. Please click the picture to check the details:

1. Find your channel in Teams and get links to channel:
   [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNac.png)
2. String after "channel/" is ChannelId:
   [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2s2c.png)
3. String after "groupId=" is TeamId:
   [picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxShP.png)

Hope they work for you.